# jquery on() data parameter - $(this) refers to the entire document

Tags: jquery, this

When using jquery, I have frequently made use of `$(this)` within events, functions, etc.

Recently I tried the following:

```
function btn_edit_click (event) {
    alert(event.data.idnum);
}
$(".btn_edit").on("click", { idnum: $(this).attr("title") }, btn_edit_click);
```

For some reason I get the title of the entire PAGE, rather than the element(s) being referenced by `$(".btn_edit")`. Am I doing something wrong, or is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it depends what this code is nested within. If the answer is nothing then `this` refers to the `window` object.

If you were referring to `this` inside an event handler then `this` would refer to the element on which the event triggered. But it appears as though you are using `this` in the global space.

If you want the title of the `.btn_edit` element to be accessible in the callback function just refer to `this` in your callback function (notice how it simplifies your code as well):

```
function btn_edit_click (event) {
    alert(this.title);
    //UPDATE: I changed $(this).attr('title') to this.title because it performs much faster
}
$(".btn_edit").on("click", btn_edit_click);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gRK3z/

Also here is a performance test to show the difference between using `.attr('title')` and `.title`: http://jsperf.com/jquery-attr-title-vs-title

Comment: I like this solution, however, does the 2nd alert make sense anymore since you aren't passing the data object?

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for the input, I think my edit crossed your comment somewhere over the Mid-West...

Comment: this seems simplest...I didn't realize that when you don't declare the function inline, you can still refer to "this"...I also didn't realize that this.title is faster :P...thanks

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` is being called within the global scope here, not within a callback method.  So yes, you should expect to get the window or document object back with `$(this)`.

A better solution might be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function btn_edit_click (event) {
    alert(event.data.idnum);
}

$('.btn_edit').each(function(k, el)
{
    $(el).on('click', { idnum: $(el).attr('title') }, btn_edit_click);
});
</script>
```

Comment: ah...makes sense...i just removed the "data" and changed the function to: function () { btn_edit_click($(this).attr("title")) }

Comment: A better practise would be ditching the .each() and use the .on() already on the element.

Answer (score 1):

The context of `this` is not what you expect it to be, as others have pointed out. I think this is a less convoluted and more readable way of doing what it is you are trying to do:

```
$("#parentDiv").delegate(".btn_edit", "click", function (e) {
    btn_edit_click(this.title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are passing an object to the `on` function, so `this` is whatever it is in the scope you're in.

Unless set, `this` is usually set to `window`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating an object to pass data across it is not in the scope of the selector. Instead you could simply pass the name of your function to be executed in the handler.

`this` in your function would then relate to the element as specified in your selector, saving the need for you to pass the object in the first place:

```
function btn_edit_click (event) {
    alert($(this).attr("title"));
}
$(".btn_edit").on("click", btn_edit_click);
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upzVL/)**